# jQuery UI, syntax for children of element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to refer to a child of element in function on event?

This way not working:

```
$(function() {

    $("#sortable1").sortable({
        start: function() {
            $('#sortable1:first-child').addClass('some')
       },

    });

});
```

Comment: Take your pick: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/child-filter-selectors/ and http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/

Comment: Thanks, kapantzak, Federico klez Culloca, both solutions works perfect

Comment: In that case, an upvote to both of us costs you nothing :)

Comment: Federico klez Culloca, i did, but a lack of reputation makes my upvotes invisible

Comment: @Алиса: your account is still able to accept answers. [Read more here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+accept+an+answer+at+stack+overflow) on how to do so. Answer acceptance is not strictly mandatory here, but it is recommended, and is the best way to thank people who help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#sortable1').children().eq(0).addClass('some')
```

Answer (score 2):

Each sortable item is assigned a class: `ui-sortable-handle`. You can then select this in your `start` callback.

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortable1").sortable({
    start: function() {
      $(this).find(".ui-sortable-handle").eq(0).addClass('some');
      /* OR:
      $(this).find(".ui-sortable-handle").filter(":first").addClass('some');
      */
    }
  });
});
```

See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

If this item is moved, the class you added will be carried along. If another item, later,  is "first", it too will have the `some` class assigned to it.

Comment: Thanks, i get it, but a task is wider. Sorting between three lists, all items in source and target lists must changin properties almost in every possible event (become displayed or not, applying and removing a children, etc.. )

Comment: @АлисаФамина Sounds like you are making a lot of work for yourself. Would move that extra info to a `.data()` store.

Comment: Yes, i try to make an app which will help me in my work (food delivery). It will looks like this: [imgur link](https://i.imgur.com/1nhwuFtr.png) and will be used like this: [imgur link](https://i.imgur.com/MYzfdkJr.png). 
Admin part is already finished, need to make a front screen with drag-n-drop. It will work via browser, but maybe later i will learn, how to make from it an Android app (if i will find a time for this).

> Would move that extra info to a `.data()` store. 
-- I will try to learn about it, tnx.

Comment: @АлисаФамина it seems like you are moving a single item ina group of items from one column to another. thus removing the item from the original group and adding it to another group. I would not use Sortable for this; since your operation will be more complex. Would advise Drag and Droppable.

Comment: Thank's for advise, but IMHO, Sortable fits best. I really need to sort items between three connected lists. I just whant to make lists looks like card deck or pile of coins, where only top item is visible. In that picture, a group, it's not a column. Every cell is a group and contains `ul`. Every cell represents, how many pieces of serving is in a certain state (ordered, sold or in a rest), and every `li` is one piece. User moves one piece (one `li`) from one group to another.

Comment: Yes, you get it. But your example does not work correctly: [imgur link](https://i.imgur.com/9xHpSZy.png). I hope that over the weekend I can make it my way, with Sortable, then show the result. After that will be a next step, updating MySQL table on every change without page reloading. I guess, then i will have a bunch of new questions, but not now. Thank you, i will bookmarking your example for future.

Comment: @АлисаФамина I started my example with sortable and found that it really did not like having each item on top of each other. Items kept getting lost in the stack or put in the wrong place. As I made it, the more I found that it might be better to remove the lists and just use counters. You can still move items from one to the other, but having them as lists was making it more difficult.

Comment: With Sortable: [https://jsfiddle.net/alisa23a/j5b0qpr9/](https://jsfiddle.net/alisa23a/j5b0qpr9/)

Answer (score 1):

`$('#sortable1:first-child')` points to the first child of `document` (I think) that has id `sortable1`. You need to specify what the child is.

For example if it is a `span` you need `$('#sortable1 span:first-child')`